# Adding cells at specific index

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, rowdatabound

I have gridview with autogenerated columns.I have added a column dynamically in the row databound event.

```
     if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        TableCell cell1 = new TableCell();
        e.Row.Cells.Add(cell1);
    }

       // to add header
    else
    {
        TableCell cell1 = new TableCell();
        cell1.Text = "<span style='font-weight:bold'>NAME";
        e.Row.Cells.Add(cell1);
    }
```

This column gets added at the end.
I want to add this column in the index 2.

Any one can help me please?
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **[AddAt(int index, TableCell cell)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.tablecellcollection.addat.aspx)** instead

**Example:**

```
e.Row.Cells.AddAt(2, cell1);
```

Hope this will help !!